# coldfusion - storing text as binary data

Tags: coldfusion, binary, type-conversion

I'd like to store my text as a binary data with coldfusion. The problem I'm having is that the file ends up being binary-encoded text stored as text.

this is the code I'm using

```
// create
FileWrite(LOCAL_FILE_DATA, binaryEncode(toBinary(toBase64("")),"Hex"));

// append
LOCAL_FILE = FileOpen(LOCAL_FILE_DATA,"append");
FileWrite( LOCAL_FILE, binaryEncode(toBinary(toBase64(LOCAL_DATA)),"Hex") );
```

Is there something simple I'm missing that is causing information to be saved as text rather than binary?

if I only use `FileWrite( LOCAL_FILE, toBinary(toBase64(LOCAL_DATA)) );`, then it only writes the text data

the data I'm trying to write looks something like this `"2013-08-04 07:49:21","::1","","","","","","","","","","","",""` I'm using a local server so the ip is not being resolved, I'm either seeing that in the file or something like this `22323031332D30382D30342030343A31333A3038222C223A3A31222C22222C22222C2`

but in both cases the file is a text file.

Comment: Do you have a sample of the before data and the desire after?

Comment: Curious as to why you would choose to store text as binary data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Am I missing something, or is the reason your file output ends up being binary encoded text because you're very specifically converting it to that with `binaryEncode()` before you write it?

If you don't want to do that then... well... *don't*!

Comment: then I end up with straight text

Comment: even if you leave this `toBinary(toBase64(LOCAL_DATA))` ?

Comment: That's not true, Daniel. If you call `isBinary()`, you get binary output. Can you post the inputs, the code, and the output that results when you are seeing this behaviour?